# LCD printing blocks

Tags: arduino, soldering, lcd, wire

Over the last couple days I have attempted to get my LCD to print "hello world". However for some reason not matter what code I upload from the liquid crystal examples on the Arduino program, it always prints blocks (shown below):
[image]

It has been an incredibly frustrating process, I checked that I have soldered all header pins properly and re-wired several times but I still get the same outcome. I have read on some websites that this is a problem due to my LCD being uninitialized. If this is the case, how do I initialize it?

Below are some photos of my LCD:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Got backlight so there is power. Got squares; did you try adjusting the pot? Maybe the contrast is turned all the way down. You're using the Arduino ver 1.6 IDE? The LiquidCrystal example HelloWorld code? Using same pin connections in comment block? (I can't tell from the photo whether LCD D7..D4 are wired correctly) Verify the code includes `lcd.begin(16,2);` and `lcd.print("whatever");` in the `setup()` function?

Comment: Please include the code you are using to write to the LCD.

Comment: The **single** row of blocks is a strong indication that the display is not initialized properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This appears to be the same module](http://www.dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/connecting_a_1602a_lcd_display_and_a_light_sensor_to_arduino_uno.html) and may even be the tutorial you are following.

That tutorial gives sample code for writing to the LCD.

What you see on the LCD is what the tutorial shows happening when there's no communication with the Arduino.

Either your code is not correct (compare with code sample in the link given above) or the serial signals aren't getting to the LCD.  Check your code, then double check the connections between the UNO and the LCD Module.

```
//code sample from http://www.dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/connecting_a_1602a_lcd_display_and_a_light_sensor_to_arduino_uno.html   
        #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

        LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11 , 12);

        void setup() {
          lcd.begin(16, 2);
          lcd.setCursor(0,1);
          lcd.write("LIGHT: ");
        }

        void loop() { }
```